# gssd: What is <anyname>?

Tags: nfs, kerberos

`rpc.gssd`'s man says:

```
rpc.gssd searches in the following order for a principal to use. The first matching credential is used. For the search, <hostname> and <REALM> are replaced with the local system's hostname and Kerberos realm.

   <HOSTNAME>$@<REALM>
   root/<hostname>@<REALM>
   nfs/<hostname>@<REALM>
   host/<hostname>@<REALM>
   root/<anyname>@<REALM>
   nfs/<anyname>@<REALM>
   host/<anyname>@<REALM>

The <anyname> entries match on the service name and realm, but ignore the hostname. These can be used if a principal matching the local host's name is not found.
```

What is `<anyname>`? A hostname not equal to the machine's hostname? Or `<anyname>` literally?

Answer (score 1):

The former. Just any hostname.

> but ignore the hostname.

Comment: The non-matching "hostname" does not need to be fully qualified.